# calculate total number of days in specied dates

Tags: php, sql, mysql, date

i have one table with two columns as shown in picture

[image]

table columns names are (MAXDATE,AMOUNT).

if you see we have

```
   first date range (from current date to 20-jan-2010)
   second date range from 20-jan-2010 to 30-jan-2010 
   3rd range is from 20-jan-2010 to 31-jan-2010.
```

at the execution of page user enter the start and end date.

for example, if user put

```
      start date: 18-jan-2010
      end date: 23-jan-2010
```

then he has 2 dates in first options and 3 dates in second options.

what i want to calculate in sql

```
1. how many days in first range (if any this depends on supplied dates from user)
2. how many days in 2nd range  (if any this depends on supplied dates from user)
3. how many days in 3rd range  (if any this depends on supplied dates from user)
```

Thanks

Comment: You should consider changing your schema to include a start and end date, eg. (start_date, end_date, amount).

Comment: I don't understand the part about the user input. Could you show which ranges you want to calculate assuming you example? Thanks.

Comment: Ah I think I understand what you mean. In your example first range is 18-jan to 20-jan, second 20-jan to 23-jan and the last range is 0 days, right?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example how to calculate days.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-calculations.html

Comment: Direct addition/subtraction of dates only works if you are working with isolated units (years, months within the same year, or days within the same month). `DAY(date1)-DAY(date2)` will not work for this application. I think you meant to link to: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Answer (score 0):

You can do all of this in MySQL:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(NOW(), max_date) as days;
SELECT DATEDIFF(date2, date1) FROM
    (SELECT max_date as date1 FROM table1 LIMIT 1) as s1
    JOIN 
    (SELECT max_date as date2 FROM table1 LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1) as s2;
//etc.
```